# Set Firestore documents with partially merged fields - Firestore limitation

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the Python library of Firestore to communicate with Firestore.

I have now run into a limitation of Firestore and I am wondering if there is a way around it.

Imagine we have this map / Dict (dictVar1):

```
dictVar1 = {
    "testArray": ["Yes"],
    "testMap": {
        "test1": 1,
        "test2": 1
    }
}
```

To begin with, I used to store my testMap in an array, but due to Firestore query limitations (you can only have a single array-contains operation in a query), I changed my structure to a map instead (as you can see in the dictVar1 structure above). If Firestore queries did not have this limitation, I would not change my structure from an array.

Now I am facing another Firestore limitation due to the new structure.

What I would like to do & other conditions:

1. I want to add this map / dict to a Firestore document.
2. I would like to do it in one Firestore operation using Firestore batch
3. I don't know if the document exists or not before updating/creating
4. One batch can contain anything between 1 and 500 operations
5. If the document exists, I do not want to remove any other fields from the existing document if these fields are not present in dictVar1 dict / map.
6. The fields in dictVar1 dict / map should replace the fields in the document completely

So if the existing document would contain this data:

```
{

    "doNotChange": "String",
    "testMap": {
        "test0": 1
    }
}
```

It would be updated to ("test0" is removed from the inner map, basically how an array would work):

```
{
    "doNotChange": "String",
    "testArray": ["Yes"],
    "testMap": {
        "test1": 1,
        "test2": 1
    }
}
```

And if the document doesn't exist, the document would be set to:

```
{
    "testArray": ["Yes"],
    "testMap": {
        "test1": 1,
        "test2": 1
    }
}
```

I see two ways to do this:

1. Do this in two operations
2. Instead of using testMap as a map, replace it with an array.

99% of the time the document exists, therefore I am fine with doing this in two operations if the document doesn't exist, but one operation if the document exists.

This could be done using Firestore's update function, but since I am using batch and potentially updating 100s of documents in one batch, if the document doesn't exist, it would ruin the whole batch operation.

Another potential solution would be to:

1. Run batch with updates, if it succeeds, then great, if 404 (document not found) is raised then:
2. Change the operation to set instead of an update for this document and then redo the batch, in a loop until the batch is successful

Two potential problems I see with this:

1. Will I be fully charged for all the failed batch operations or will I be just be charged 1 read per failed batch operation? If I get fully charged for the batch, then this is still not a good solution.
2. Is it possible to easily change the operation type for a specific document reference to a different operation type without having to recreate the batch operation totally from scratch?

Do you have any ideas on how I could solve one of these problems?

Here is the Python code to test out:

```
from json import dumps
from google.cloud import firestore

db = firestore.Client.from_service_account_json("firebaseKeysDev.json")

originalDoc = {

    "doNotChange": "String",
    "testMap": {
        "test0": 1
    }
}

dictVar1 = {
    "testArray": ["Yes"],
    "testMap": {
        "test1": 1,
        "test2": 1
    }
}

prefOutput = {
    "doNotChange": "String",
    "testArray": [
        "Yes"
    ],
    "testMap": {
        "test1": 1,
        "test2": 1
    }
}

# Let's first create the document with the original dict / map
originalSetOp = db.collection("test").document("testDoc").set(originalDoc)

# Now let's get the original map / dict from Firestore
originalOpDoc = db.collection("test").document("testDoc").get()
# Convert to Python Dict
originalOpDocDict = originalOpDoc.to_dict()

# Now let's print out the original document dict
print("Here is the original map:")
print(dumps(originalOpDocDict, ensure_ascii=False, sort_keys=True, indent=4))

# Now let's merge the original dict / map with our dictVar1 dict / map
mergeDictVar1WithODoc = db.collection("test").document("testDoc").set(dictVar1, merge=True)

# Now let's get the new merged map / dict from Firestore
newDictDoc = db.collection("test").document("testDoc").get()
# Convert to Python Dict
newDictDocDict = newDictDoc.to_dict()

# Let's print the new merged dict / map
print("\nHere is the merged map:")
print(dumps(newDictDocDict, ensure_ascii=False, sort_keys=True, indent=4))

print("\nHere is the output we want:")
print(dumps(prefOutput, ensure_ascii=False, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

Output:

Here is the original map:

```
{
    "doNotChange": "String",
    "testMap": {
        "test0": 1
    }
}
```

Here is the map we want to merge:

```
{
    "testArray": [
        "Yes"
    ],
    "testMap": {
        "test1": 1,
        "test2": 1
    }
}
```

Here is the merged map:

```
{
    "doNotChange": "String",
    "testArray": [
        "Yes"
    ],
    "testMap": {
        "test0": 1,
        "test1": 1,
        "test2": 1
    }
}
```

Here is the output we want:

```
{
    "doNotChange": "String",
    "testArray": [
        "Yes"
    ],
    "testMap": {
        "test1": 1,
        "test2": 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `.set()` with `SetOptions` of `merge` or `mergeFields` *instead* of `.update()` - the field, in this case, would be your map.

Specifically, `.set()` will create a document if it doesn't exist.  It seems (I'm not on the Firebase team) the PURPOSE of .update() failing is to signal the document doesn't already exist.

I use this *extensively* in a wrapper library I created for Firestore in my app.

[Documented Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.SetOptions)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this will not solve my problem if the document exists and the testMap field is populated with {"testMap": {"test0": 1}} and I want to replace it with {"testMap": {"test1": 1}}. Merge would just append the key and value to the testMap dict / map, which is not what I want. EDIT: And I can't use set without merge because if the document exists, it might contain other fields I do not want to remove by just setting the document.

Comment: Here is the code: https://i.imgur.com/wtypK5b.png
Here is the output: https://i.imgur.com/m07vJca.png. This is not what I am trying to achieve. What I would like to do is to replace "testMap" and not just append the existing key/values. So partially merge some fields while not the rest. I also tried mergeFields as a list, but that does not work either

Comment: Here is a picture with the original map we have, what happens when we merge, and the output we want, but we don't get: https://i.imgur.com/NxvxcH1.png

Comment: Of course. Here you go: https://trinket.io/python/f4b9db6b67

Comment: The code is synchronous, the logic: 1) It creates/replaces the document "testDoc" in the collection "test" with the map named "originalDoc". 2) Then I retrieve the same document map and print it out, to show the original structure of the object in Firestore. 3) Then I set the map with the name dictVar1 to Firestore using the set operation with merge=True option. 4) Then I re-retrieve that document again to show the new and merged structure. I have also added the print output of the code to the main post. Maybe set operation with Merge might be different in Javascript vs Python?

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but I do not think you quite understand the problem here. This issue has nothing to do with Python or Firestore being synchronous or not. Even if I just have a simple set with Merge without using the get operation, the results would be the same. If you want to contribute to solving the problem, I would recommend reading through the post and the comments first to fully understand the problem